# Proportional equality constraints

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

Consider a node $s$. Let's assume that there are three outgoing arcs from node $s$ namely $(s,i)$,$(s,j)$ and $(s,k)$. Corresponding to each of these arcs, there is a flow proportion value $t_{sj}\in (0,1]$. It means that the amount of flow along the arc $(s,j)$ should be $t_{sj} *f_{ps}$ in which $f_{ps}$ is flow over the single arc going to node $s$. Now in my LP I have the following constraints regarding node $s$:

1. $f_{ps}  =  f_{si}+f_{sj}+f_{sk}$
2. $ f_{si} =  t_{si} *f_{ps}$
3. $ f_{sj} =  t_{sj} *f_{ps}$
4. $ f_{sk} =  t_{sk} *f_{ps}$

In a special case, just assume that $\sum_j {t_{sj}}=1$. For example assume that $t_{sj}$ are probability values.

Now, my question is that how I can getting rid of these proportional equality constraints, i.e. constraints  2-4 in our given example. I am looking for a way to modify the structure of the network in such a way to include these constraints implicitly.

Comment: Are $t_{sj}$ and $f_{ps}$ (for all relevant values of $s, j, p$) both decision variables? If so, your problem looks similar to what are called "pooling problems". A recent reference can be found [here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ie100025e). These problems are nonconvex, and there is no known way to reformulate these programs so that they can be solved efficiently (that is, in polynomial time).

Comment: t_{sj} is a constant but f_{ps} is a variable. This is the case for all t and f notations.